# How to efficiently stream text to screen in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I want to stream a bunch of text to display the status/progress of a long running task (such as the output window in Visual Studio).

Currently I have something like this XAML:

```
    <ScrollViewer Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="12" Height="129" Name="scrollViewer1" Width="678">
        <TextBlock Name="text"  TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

and this code behind:

```
    private void Update(string content)
    {
        text.Text += content + "\n";
        scrollViewer1.ScrollToBottom();
    }
```

After a while, it gets really slow.
Is there a recommended way of doing this type of thing?  Am I using the right kinds of controls?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by really slow? Slow to scroll? The overall app gets slow as you navigate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a minimum, you'll want to use a readonly `TextBox` and use the `AppendText()` method to append text.

Of course, you're still not immune from performance problems if you have sufficient volumes of text. That being the case, you might need to look into virtualization (both data and UI) solution.

Comment: I was surprised by TextBox choice over TextBlock. Wanted to test their performance and test totally reflected your point, Kent. Adding 100K words to a TextBlock took 91625ms, while for a TextBox it's only 10737ms.